# Disable/enable notification led

Tags: android, led

Is it possible to programmatically disable and enable the led indicator light on an Android device? I am not referring to just turning it on and off as in a notification. I did not see anything in the api that would do so. I am guessing this is hardware specific if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not seen any APIs for dealing with the LEDs other than the `Notification` class.

Comment: I don't believe there is anything in the Notification class that will allow you to disable the led or am I missing something?

Comment: @martinjd: Correct. Hence, I do not think there are any APIs in Android that let you disable the LEDs. I apologize for not making that clearer in my original answer.

Answer (score 9):

Yea sure there is a way...

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
            "notification_light_pulse", 1);
```

1 - indicate on state

0 - indicate off state