# Permanently enable and disable blinking LED notification light in android programmatically

Tags: android, notifications, led

I have been looking for the ability to disable and enable the LED notification light through code. I saw this thread [Disable/enable notification led](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304971/disable-enable-notification-led), but it is quite old and I was wondering if the new API versions has some support for turning it off completely.

Comment: read the documentation on notification http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if the new API versions has some support for turning it off completely

You cannot enable or disable the LED behavior through the Android SDK, except within your own app, where you control what any `Notification` does that you raise.

Answer (score 0):

You can only control the led if your app raies a notification when no other apps have raised a notifiction.

It is possible on some devices to bypass android and control it directly in unix shell, but this is obviously not recommended.