# Activate blocking mode programmatically

Tags: android, settings, android-4.2-jelly-bean

since Android 4.2 (I guess) there is the new [blocking mode](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-kRd5QEkcT_U/UdlvmHdSwSI/AAAAAAAABVk/CiB2qWaW9C0/s1600/blocking-mode.jpg) feature.

I'd like to toggle (activate/deactivate) this feature from my app. I know that I can change basically everything about sounds via the SDK but I couldn't find a single article about how to toggle blocking mode.

Comment: As far as I know this is a Samsung feature. That's why you won't find any official android documentation about that. That known even if you are able to use it you won't be able to use it on non-Samsung phones.

Comment: Thanks, @CommonsWare said basically the same. I'm still looking for a way to disable the front LED. Any idea?

Comment: Whoops. Didn't see the answer while I was answering. I think that is not possible for notifications that are not those from your own app refering to @CommonsWare 's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10858496/3160089). Or does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15409789/3160089) work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not from stock Android. Whatever it is comes from your device manufacturer. You will have to ask them what that is and whether or not there is an API for controlling it that ordinary SDK apps can hold.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you! But how can I disable the front LED during the night? There must be some way...

Comment: @Ron: "But how can I disable the front LED during the night?" -- put a piece of electrical tape over it. :-) Beyond that, I am not aware of any way to accomplish this programmatically.