# Access android notification led directly?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is it possible to access the notification led without creating a new notification?
I would like to make it change colors over time but when I just change the color of an existing notification it is not smooth and only works when the device is locked.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this. Android API doesn't have any method which would allow it.

Comment: I've seen another method to en/disable the led could it be a method to access it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304971

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any working solution in the topic you've posted.